# How can I make an AngularJS directive to stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, stoppropagation

I am trying to "stopPropagation" to prevent a Twitter Bootstrap navbar dropdown from closing when an element (link) inside an li is clicked.  Using this method seems to be the common [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323066/twitter-bootstrap-stop-propagation-on-dropdown-open).

In Angular, seems like a directive is the place to do this?  So I have:

```
// do not close dropdown on click
directives.directive('stopPropagation', function () {
    return {
        link:function (elm) {            
            $(elm).click(function (event) {                
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

... but the method does not belong to element:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'stopPropagation'
```

I tie in the directive with

```
<li ng-repeat="foo in bar">
  <div>
    {{foo.text}}<a stop-propagation ng-click="doThing($index)">clickme</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should make some room in the tags for [tag:javascript] (or even [tag:jquery]).

Comment: Good suggestion.  Made the edit.

Comment: The reason the `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't work in your code is that AngularJS and jQuery have *two separate event cycles*. That's one reason why it's generally a bad idea to use them both. Your click event defined with `ngClick` uses Angular, but you're trying to use jQuery to stop the event propagation.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

*"Currently some directives (i.e. ng:click) stops event propagation. This prevents interoperability with other frameworks that rely on capturing such events."* - [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/259)

... and was able to fix without a directive, and simply doing:

```
<a ng-click="doThing($index); $event.stopPropagation();">x</a>
```

Comment: This was perfect. I had a dropdown with a form in it. I added ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" to the div around the form and that fixed the dropdown from going away when the form inputs were clicked. Thanks!

Comment: simple solution. worked perfectly. I would prefer this rather than creating a directive.

Comment: Indeed, simplier than having to create a directive. works fine for me. Thanks

Comment: Simple for a single-use scenario. I'd recommend using a directive to anyone who needs to use this code in multiple places throughout the view - for one, it's easier to extend the functionality, handle more events, and especially to try to keep logic out of the markup as much as possible. Cheers!

Comment: This strategy does not works if we click on another button,link.The current link does not gets closed

Answer (score 156):

I've used this way: Created a directive:

```
    .directive('stopEvent', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if(attr && attr.stopEvent)
                    element.bind(attr.stopEvent, function (e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    });
            }
        };
     });
```

that could be used this way:

```html
<a ng-click='expression' stop-event='click'>
```

This is more generic way of stopping propagation of any kind of events.

Comment: BTW, can you elaborate on the restrict keyword?  Not finding a good resource for what that means exactly.

Comment: Sure! http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive "Directive Definition Object": restrict - String of subset of EACM which restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style. If omitted directives are allowed on attributes only.

Comment: This is an interesting approach... I like it.  Thanks!

Comment: Same solution for .prefentDefault() in IE7 to keep page reloads from happening.  Great Solution!

Comment: Oh lord i love directives

Comment: This does not work for me in Safari Mobile iOS 7. But the $event.stopProgation(); works.

Comment: var to = attr.ngStopEvent != "*" ? attr.ngStopEvent : 'blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error';  // to support wildcard in element.bind(to,

Comment: Yo, I added an `if(attr && attr.stopEvent)` check just to make things a little more safe. Let me know if this isn't cool. Hope it helps :]. Thanks for the great snippet

Comment: I used this solution; it works fine and it seems more "clean" for me than the selected answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my life! :) I used it to scroll content inside of angular material design bottomSheet : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet

Here is how i used it: <div class='creditdebitcard-scroll' stop-event='touchstart'>

Comment: I have a checkbox and a select inside the heading of an accordion. When pressing on the checkbox or the select, the accordion opened or closed (not the desired effect). I solved this by adding `ng-click="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();"` to the checkbox and `ng-click="$event.stopImmediatePropagation();$event.preventDefault();"` to the select, and now everything Works as expected.

Answer (score 9):

`stopPropagation` has to be called on an event object, not the element itself. Here's an example:

```js
compile: function (elm) {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        $(elm).click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the question so that the directive calls stopPropagation on event and not element.  Didn't work.  Found this: "Currently some directives (i.e. ng:click) stops event propagation. This prevents interoperability with other frameworks that rely capturing such events." - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/259

Comment: So found this to be the fix:  <a ng-click="doThing($index); $event.stopPropagation();">x</a>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple, abstract directive to stop event propagation. I figure it might be useful to someone. Simply pass in the event you wish to stop.

```
<div stopProp="click"></div>
```

```js
app.directive('stopProp', function () {
  return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    elm.on(attrs.stopProp, function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: wouldn't that need to be `stop-prop` in the element?