# AngularJS - ng-click over ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a html code like the following:

```
<div class="outerdiv" data-ng-click="resetText()">
    <div class="innerdiv" data-ng-click="showText()">
        {{ text }}
    </div>
</div>
```

An outer div with a `ng-click` and an inner div with a different `ng-click`.

My problem is: when I click the inner div, the outer one is being fired as well. What can I do to solve this (fire the inner function, not the outer one?

I can make it work using a hardcoded flag, but not sure if I'm in face of a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) problem.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/pebab/1/edit?html,js,output) illustrating the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to cancel event propagation between nested ng-click calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193539/whats-the-best-way-to-cancel-event-propagation-between-nested-ng-click-calls)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<div class="innerdiv" data-ng-click="showText($event)">
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.showText = function(event) {
    // whatever
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<div class="outerdiv" data-ng-click="resetText()">
    <div class="innerdiv" data-ng-click="showText();$event.stopPropagation()">
        {{ text }}
    </div>
</div>
```