# Prevent ng-click propagation from child to parent element in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The name of fruits are `a` elements nested within a `<div ng-repeat=".."></div>`. When this orange parent `div` is clicked, some hidden text is shown. When the fruit name is clicked, it should become bold.

**Problem:** When the fruit name is clicked, it becomes bold *AND* the hidden text is revealed. How do we allow the fruit name to be bold without the hidden text being revealed?

I believe this involves preventing propogation of the click event from the `a` to the `div`, how can we do this?

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/tf4b63km/

**Before clicking on fruit name**

[image]

**After clicking on fruit name**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15193650/1398867

Answer (score 6):

You can stop event from bubbling up by calling `stopPropagation`. In your case you need to do two things:

1) Pass `$event` to `makeBold` function: `ng-click="makeBold($event, f)"`

2) Call `stopPropagation`

```
function makeBold($event, f) {
   $event.stopPropagation();
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `e.stopPropagation();` in the `makeBold` function to stop event from bubbling up the DOM tree. This will make the parent event handlers not to run on child click.

1. Pass the `$event` object to the click handler
2. In the handler, use `stopPropagation()`

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/megdgq11/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

FruitCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.fruits = [{
    title: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    title: 'orange',
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    title: 'banana',
    color: 'yellow'
  }];

  $scope.makeBold = function(e, f) {
    console.log('makeBold')
    f.isBold = 'bold';

    // Stop event propagation here
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

```css
.fruit {
  background: #FF735C;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fruit a {
  color: #fff;
}
.fruit:hover {
  background: #3D3240;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="FruitCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat='f in fruits' class='fruit' ng-click='f.show = !f.show'>
      <a href="#" ng-click='makeBold($event, f)' ng-style='{"font-weight": f.isBold}'>{{ f.title }}</a>
      <!--                           ^^^^^^ Pass event object --->
      <div ng-show='f.show'>
        {{ f.color }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```