# Stop Angular Dropdown Selection From Changing Model Immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="thing"
        data-ng-options="thing.id as thing.name for thing in things"
        ng-change="doSomething()">
</select>
```

I have some code like that above. When a user picks a "thing", it changes the model immediately. Instead, I would like to pop a modal and ask if the user is sure he would like the change to happen BEFORE the model changes. Is there a good way to do this. I looked into a couple stop propagation ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544741/how-can-i-make-an-angularjs-directive-to-stoppropagation), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193539/whats-the-best-way-to-cancel-event-propagation-between-nested-ng-click-calls)) solutions, but I am not sure that's a good way to handle this.

In short, how do I achieve my goal here?

Edit: `window.event.stopPropagation();`does NOT stop the change.

Comment: wait for angular 2.0, there two way banding is not default :D

Comment: haha sounds like a plan.

Comment: Just have the `ngModel` be a different model, then on the prompt confirm, assign the value to your actual structure.

Comment: Thanks tyme, that seems like a good way to go. I didn't realize how much I was over-complicating.