# js how to avoid unwanted click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `angular.js` and I have a table where each row is able to click, using `ng-click="launchMethodRow"`,  but in a determinate column in the row I have a button, when I clicked in that button, not only functionality of this button is triggered (`ng-click="launchMethodButton"`), but also the method for the row is launched.

How can I do to avoid this behaviour? I want when I click the button, only the method that the button responds run and not the method for row.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193539/whats-the-best-way-to-cancel-event-propagation-between-nested-ng-click-calls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the event associated with the click and prevent it from propagating.

Lets say you have a row and a button like so:

```
<div class="row" ng-click="launchMethodRow()">
    <button ng-click="launchMethodButton($event)"></button>
</div>
```

For the button `ng-click` pass the click event (`$event`) down to the callback function. And in the `launchMethodButton` function, stop event propagation.

```
$scope.launchMethodButton = function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // execute button click logic
}
```

**OR**

Alternatively, you could wrap propagation stopping logic into a directive and can apply that to the button and that way you wouldn't have to do that logic in controller.

```
angular.module('someModule', []).directive('stopClickPropagation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    }
});

<div class="row" ng-click="launchMethodRow()">
        <button ng-click="launchMethodButton()" stop-click-propagation></button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll take the directive approach, in order to reuse.

Comment: @mos Perfect. That way when unit testing, you can just test the directive once and don't have to keep on testing the same logic in every controller with this logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use $event.stopPropagation() for this :

```
 <div ng-click="clicked('outer')">
      <div ng-click="clicked('inner'); $event.stopPropagation()"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` to disable the button so that you can avoid unwanted click.

```
<input type="button" value="Login" ng-show="myForm.$valid" ng-click="sigClick(username,password)">
```

the button will be able to click only when the for is valid

Comment: each row always has to show this button, the button is an integral part of each row.

Comment: Ok no problem you see the `input type button` will always visible to the user but it will not able to be clickable untill the condition become true look here `ng-disabled="myForm.$valid"`