# Two nested click events with angularjs

Tags: javascript, function, angularjs

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div ng-click="test()">
    <div id="myId" ng-click="test2()"></div>
    <div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Currently when I click on the `div` with the id `myId` then both functions get triggered, but I want that just `test2` function get triggered. How can I do that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544741/angularjs-directive-to-stoppropagation where a directive is defined to stop propagation.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

All you need to do is to stop event propagation/bubbling.

This code will help you:

```
<div ng-click="test()">ZZZZZ
    <div id="myId" ng-click="test2();$event.stopPropagation()">XXXXX</div>
    <div>YYYYYY</div>
    ...
</div>
```

If your `test` and `test2` functions would look as follows, you would get only `test2` in your console when clicking on `myId` DIV. Without `$event.stopPropagation()` you would get `test2` followed by `test` in the console output window.

```
$scope.test = function() {
    console.info('test');
}
$scope.test2 = function() {
    console.info('test2');
}
```

Comment: Also works for Angular2: `(click)="test2();$event.stopPropagation()"`  Thanks

Answer (score 32):

Same as tom's answer, but little different.

```
        <div ng-click="test()">
            <div id="myId" ng-click="test2($event)">child</div>
        </div>

        $scope.test2 =function($event){
            $event.stopPropagation();
            console.log("from test2")
        }
        $scope.test =function(){
            console.log("from test")
        }
```

Comment: +1 to this answer for keeping that stopPropagation logic out of the view.

Comment: I think this logic **does** belong in the view, because otherwise controller makes the assumption that the inner function will always be called from that context, and that it will need to stop propagation every time. This makes the reuse of the inner function very limited. If the view ever gets refactored, then so must the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a directive based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544741/how-can-i-make-an-angularjs-directive-to-stoppropagation) which supports ng-href links.

**Directive**

```js
'use strict';


var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate'
  ]);

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name myMobileApp.directive:stopEvent
 * @description Allow normal ng-href links in a list where each list element itselve has an ng-click attached.
 */
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('stopEvent', function($location, $rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', function(event) {

        // other ng-click handlers shouldn't be triggered
        event.stopPropagation(event);
        if(element && element[0] && element[0].href && element[0].pathname) {
          // don't normaly open links as it would create a reload.
          event.preventDefault(event);
          $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $location.path( element[0].pathname );
          });
        }
      });
      }
    };
  })


.controller('TestCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'Profile', '$location', '$http', '$log',
  function($rootScope, $scope, Profile, $location, $http, $log) {
    $scope.profiles = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':3}];

    $scope.goToURL = function(path, $event) {
      $event.stopPropagation($event);
      $location.path(path);
    };

  }
]);
```

```html
  <div ng-repeat="x in profiles" 
     ng-click="goToURL('/profiles/' + x.a, $event)">

      <a stop-event ng-href="/profiles/{{x.b}}">{{x}}</a>

  </div>
```