# Child ng-click not firing

Tags: angularjs

I have nested ul\li elements. I have the same ng-click for all li elements. For some reason if I click a li element that is nested under another li element, only the parent one fires. In the case below, when I click on the "Sub One" li element, it fires the 'Two' li element twice. I know how to stop propagation but it still fires the parent ng-click. Hope that makes sense.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="doSomething()">One</li>
    <li ng-click="doSomething()">Two
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="doSomething()">Sub One</li>
            <li ng-click="doSomething()">Sub Two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="doSomething()">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please post a fiddle or something of your issue

Comment: How can you even tell which `doSomething()` was called? You're not passing anything, and `this` which is scope would be the same in each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably made something wrong, because it works perfectly. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390393/two-nested-click-events-with-angularjs), simply use `$event.stopPropagation()`. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fPGdn/1/) for instance :

```
<ul ng-app="test" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-click="doSomething($event, 1)">One</li>
    <li ng-click="doSomething($event, 2)">Two
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="doSomething($event, 21)">Sub One</li>
            <li ng-click="doSomething($event, 22)">Sub Two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-click="doSomething($event, 3)">Three</li>
</ul>
```

and :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function ($event, test)
    {
        console.log(test);
        $event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Then a click on "Sub One" just show 21 in the console.

Comment: Originally, I could access the object clicked by using 'this' inside of the function, instead I passed in the object and that works great.