# Separate click event from focus event in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I want to add a click handler to an `ng-focus` callback, to start listening to all future click events. But when focus is initiated by a click, the click handler fires immediately as well. I can solve the problem with a `$timeout`, but this is a hack and it goes against everything I stand for. What have I become?!

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="q" ng-focus="inputFocus($event)" />
```

This .js **works** (this is inside a directive's link function):

```
scope.inputFocus = function (e) {
    scope.displayHistory = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $document.on('click', hideHistory);
    }, 200)
};

function hideHistory() {
    scope.displayHistory = false;
    scope.$digest();
    $document.off('click')
};
```

I want the following to work, but the problem is that the click callback fires immediately. As you might expect, if I *tab* to this field, the click callback does not get called. But if the focus event is triggered by a click, `hideHistory` gets called.

```
scope.inputFocus = function (e) {
    scope.displayHistory = true;
    $document.on('click', hideHistory);
};
```

I tried calling `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` but these solutions were not effective either.

Comment: What about setting a boolean in the click function to check if focus has been fired, then only run the click function once focused equals true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `e.preventDefault();` ?

Anyway you can provide a fiddle to illustrate exactly what's going on?

Comment: Sorry, can't provide fiddle due to company policy.

Comment: Maybe check out this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439530/angularjs-directive-how-to-let-an-event-only-be-triggered-once-if-otherwise-it