# Stop a clicked link from loading and let the surrounding element with Angularjs ng-click handle the action

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom-events

I have a table of courses and initially I made each row clickable, which would then switch templates in `ng-view` and show the course's details.  My problem is that I need a search appliance's crawler to be able to follow links to the course's details in order to make them available for searching.  I have done that by adding a link to the course's title in one of the table's cells but now I have the problem of having a student actually clicking both the title link and table row.  Where/how do I cancel one of those actions, preferably the title link (I'd like to stop the page from loading twice)?  Here is an excerpt of my template:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Instructor</th>
        <th>Days</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="course in catalog.courses | filter:isSubject" ng-click="loadCourse(course.regnum,course.id)">
        <td><a href="/schedule/#!/course/{{course.regnum}}/{{course.id}}">{{course.abbr}} {{course.num}} {{course.section}}: {{course.title}}</a></td>
        <td>{{course.instructor}}</td>
        <td>{{course.meeting_pattern}}</td>
        <td>{{course.start_time}} - {{course.end_time}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When someone clicks on the link in the first cell both the link and the row's function in `ng-click` are called and the page loads twice.  I want to stop the link `href` action from happening and only let the `ng-click` action handle the request.

I know I have to stop the propagation some how but if I stop it on the `<a>` element will that affect the function on the `<tr>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ng-click="$event.preventDefault();"` to the link that you want to stop.

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in catalog.courses | filter:isSubject" ng-click="loadCourse(course.regnum,course.id)">
    <td><a href="/schedule/#!/course/{{course.regnum}}/{{course.id}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();">{{course.abbr}} {{course.num}} {{course.section}}: {{course.title}}</a></td>
    <td>{{course.instructor}}</td>
    <td>{{course.meeting_pattern}}</td>
    <td>{{course.start_time}} - {{course.end_time}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also, you were missing your closing `</a>` on that link.

Comment: Thanks, its not missing in my original code though.  I fixed the original question to reflect the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found part of the solution here: [How can I make an AngularJS directive to stopPropagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544741/angularjs-directive-to-stoppropagation)

and used the `preventDefault()` instead of the `stopPropagation()` function.

```
<a href="/schedule/#!/course/{{course.regnum}}/{{course.id}}" stop-event="click">
```

then created a directive:

```
app.directive('stopEvent',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link : function(scope,el,attr){
            el.bind(attr.stopEvent,function(evt){
                evt.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, but ended up using the accepted answer as it is more concise