# Angular How Can I only trigger child element event

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-click="process1()" id="1">
    <div ng-click="process2()" id="2">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the div which id is two, it will both trigger process1 and process2,How can I just trigger process2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should pass the `$event` from the html in the ng-click of id 2 element and then call the stopPropagation method of that event in the controller.

HTML -

```
<div ng-click="process1()" id="1">
    <div ng-click="process2($event)" id="2">
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the controller -:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.process1 = function(){
        alert(1);
    }

    $scope.process2 = function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert(2);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SSHYK/131/

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use directive for this. It will be more generalise to stop event propagation.

HTML

```
<div ng-click="process1()" id="1">
    <div ng-click="process2()" id="2" stop-event>
    </div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.process1 = function(){
    alert(1);
}

$scope.process2 = function(){
    alert(2);
}
```

and just use a directive

```
.directive('stopEvent', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6m290Lbt/3/

If you wanted, you could make this solution more generic like this answer to a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547223/347216

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `$event.stopPropagation`. Also you should avoid to name elements id with numbers.

```
<div ng-click="process1();$event.stopPropagation();" id="div1">
```

**event.stopPropagation:**

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EC8okVjhTHUfxfUv5V0E)

**References**

[event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)