# Prevent Area Tag Page Reload on Angular Ng-Click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, event-propagation

I've got an image with an associated link map. The one area tag I have in there has an ng-click on it. Currently, when you click that ng-click, the function it links to runs, but then the page reloads. How do I prevent the page from reloading in the process?

**I've even added $event.stopPropagation() to prevent the page reload**, but it's not working for some reason. Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="programApp" ng-controller="programController">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" usemap="#testMap">

  <map name="testMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,350,150" href="" ng-click="slideClick($event)">
  </map>
</div>
```

and my Angular:

```
angular.module('programApp', [
    'programApp.controllers',
]);
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope',  
    function($scope){

      $scope.slideClick = function($event){
        $event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('this ran');
      };
    }]);
```

The console log runs, showing that the function successfully runs. However, the page still reloads. How do I prevent this?

[**See Codepen here.**](http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/PqbVyv)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544741/how-can-i-make-an-angularjs-directive-to-stoppropagation

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but please look at my question: I've got the line to prevent event propagation already in there. My problem is that preventing event propagation isn't working, not that I don't have it.

Comment: Have you tried using `$event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Add $event.preventDefault(); before

Comment: Thanks, jwatts. That fixed it.

Can one of you add that as an answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the `stopPropagation()` is required for some other functionality, but I think it should be `$event.preventDefault()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't keep `href` empty. Add `#` to it.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,350,150" href="#" ng-click="slideClick($event)">

//Or
```

Use

```
$event.preventDefault();
```

The `stopPropagation` will stop the event from bubbling whereas the `preventDefault` will prevent the default action.