# Bootstrap 3 nested ULs collapse system (without JS/jQuery)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building something like a "treeview" on bootstrap3. But I'm struggling with the collapse system. There is no problem when I expand the parent. But when I try to expand a child, it expands it, but also collapse the parent. And so on...

Here is the html

```
<div class="panel-collapse" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="treeview">
      <li data-toggle="collapse" class="collapse1" href=".collapse1-1">Item 1
        <ul class="collapse collapse1-1">
          <li data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse1-1-1">Item 1-1
            <ul class="collapse collapse1-1-1">
              <li>Item 1-1-1
                <ul>
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-1</li>
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-2</li>
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Item 1-2</li>
          <li>Item 1-3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yL71kopn/

Can anyone help me on this? I would wish a purely bootstrap solution rather than a custom JS here. Unlees it's completely impossible.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323066/twitter-bootstrap-stop-propagation-on-dropdown-open

Comment: That question doesn't solve my issue, since I specifically said I did want to avoid custom JS and would prefer a pure bootstrap solution. But our friend @makshh already solved my problem with just an html element :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use links inside `li` tags, because when you click to open `Item 1-1` you are also clicking on `Item 1` `li`.

```
<div class="panel-collapse" role="tabpanel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="treeview">
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="collapse1" href=".collapse1-1">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="collapse collapse1-1">
          <li>
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse1-1-1">Item 1-1</a>
            <ul class="collapse collapse1-1-1">
              <li>Item 1-1-1
                <ul>
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-1</li>
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-2</li>
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-3</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Item 1-2</li>
          <li>Item 1-3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yL71kopn/1/)