# Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I have a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu. As all Twitter Bootstrap users know, the dropdown menu closes on click (even clicking inside it).

To avoid this, I can easily attach a click event handler on the dropdown menu and simply add the famous `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Menu item 1
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel"></li>
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <img alt="" class="img-rounded" src="img1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
              <img alt="" class="img-rounded" src="img2.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#carousel" 
             class="left carousel-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#carousel" 
             class="right carousel-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This looks easy and a very common behavior, however, and since `carousel-controls` (as well as `carousel indicators`) event handlers are delegated to the `document` object, the `click` event on these elements (**prev/next** controls, ...) will be “ignored”.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    // The event won't be propagated up to the document NODE and 
    // therefore delegated events won't be fired
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Relying on Twitter Bootstrap dropdown `hide`/`hidden` events is not a solution for the following reasons:

- The provided event object for both event handlers does not give reference to the clicked element
- I don't have control over the dropdown menu content so adding a `flag` class or attribute is not possible

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zend_php_dev/80oLdtbf/1/) is the normal behavior and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zend_php_dev/80oLdtbf/2/) is with `event.stopPropagation()` added.

### Update

Thanks to Roman for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25196101/3165879). I also found an [answer that you can find below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25253002/3165879).

Comment: 1. Your jsfiddle is not working. 2. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @paulalexandru, Updated, added two fiddle. One default behavior, and one with modification. Try clicking on the next & previous button, or on indicators. For the first example, the menu hides & the carousel slides. or the second example : The menu stays open, but the carousel didn't slide since the `event propagation` has been stopped.

Comment: @paulalexandru Got it, Right?

Comment: @php-dev: i have updated it again for sake of challenge, now it is perfect... see the demo.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Removing the data attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` and implementing the open/close of the dropdown can be a solution.

First by handling the click on the link to open/close the dropdown like this :

```
$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown a').on('click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

and then listening the clicks outside of the dropdown to close it like this :

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').is(e.target) 
        && $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').has(e.target).length === 0 
        && $('.open').has(e.target).length === 0
    ) {
        $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown').removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Here is the demo :
http://jsfiddle.net/RomaLefrancois/hh81rhcm/2/

Comment: This solution is working fine. The bounty should be awarded to you if there is no other answer.

Comment: You seem also to be the only one who understood the situation/requirement :)

Comment: Your solution is working, generic and also "popular". The bounty should be awarded to your answer. I also found an answer, look at it below ;)

Comment: Just a tiny update:

    $('a.dropdown-toggle:not([data-toggle])').on('click', function (e) {
            var a = $(e.delegateTarget);
            var li = a.parent();

            li.parent().find('.open').removeClass('open');
            li.addClass('open');
    });

Comment: and what with multi-item in primary navigation ?
e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/hh81rhcm/61/ (if you click **Menu item 1** and after **Menu item 2**)

Comment: @Cichy...just modify the first handler like this...$('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown a').on('click', function (event) {
   $('li.dropdown.mega-dropdown.open').removeClass('open'); $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});

Comment: `$(this).parent().toggleClass('open');` didn't work for me, I used this instead `$(this).parents('.btn-group').toggleClass('open');`

Comment: This preferred answer is a hack. wow!!! Here is a simpler BOOTSTRAP 4 ALPHA answer to prevent inside click in a mega-dropdown. `// PREVENT INSIDE CLICK DROPDOWN` 
            `$('.dropdown-menu').on("click.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();                
            });`

Comment: @FrankThoeny your example works fine in Bootstrap 3 too, had similar issue and works perfectly fine. "Roma" you could add this to the answer as well. Easier and cleaner. ex: attach a class to links and then do $('.LINK_CLASS').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });

Comment: This one didn't work for me so I published my own answer down the page which fixed the problem without bringing any side problem.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()` is the best solution.

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552712/angular-4-mega-menu-is-not-closed-after-clicked-on-a-menu-inside-it @Roma

Comment: You need to add " mega-dropdown " class to that li you removed the data-toggle="dropdown". in order for it to work

Comment: This solution does not respect aria-expended attribute.

Comment: Thanks, @nacholibre - your comment works for me with just adding stopPropagation

Comment: For bootstrap 5 change data-toggle attrib to data-bs-toggle and use code like this
$("#idOfDropdown").dropdown('toggle');

Comment: @FrankThoeny Please read carefully the requirement! I don't need the dropdown to close, but I need other behavious to keep working (such as carousel slides, tabs navigation, ... whatever )

Comment: Just to add a minor improvement: use `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {...}, true)` to fire the listener during the capturing phase. I noticed that if there are two dropdown buttons, clicking on another dropdown button does not close the current dropdown without setting `useCapture` to true, possibly because the default dropdown toggle stops event propagation.

Answer (score 449):

This should help as well

```js
$(document).on('click', 'someyourContainer .dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: That's the most common solution, but I have a different requirement.

Please carefully read my question :)

Comment: @HaBa-Media I've even talked about this solution in my question second line.

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Cleaner, shorter and doesn't disable normal link behaviour which other answers do

Comment: simple, elegant and pretty usefull. Just saved me lots of time exploring bootstrap javascript/elements graph. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will not work if the 'click' event is supposed to trigger further JS actions. The dropdown will not close yes, but all the other events triggered by the click event won't fire anymore.

Comment: Best solution indeed. I personally used `'.dropdown-menu :not(.dropdown-item)'` so that clicking on a `dropdown-item` does close the popup, but clicking on a `dropdown-header` does not.

Comment: Everyone needs to stop saying this is the best solution, IT IS NOT. The OP addressed this in the question and correctly does not want to use this solution, so this does not answer OP's question. This is begging for a future bug that can be very difficult to debug. Let's say a future dev comes along and attaches a click handler to this menu. The handler will never fire, because this solution has stopped propagation. The future dev will go crazy trying to understand why this isn't working. Just because code works doesn't mean it's right or the best way.

Comment: /**with querySelectorAll => */
 document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu').forEach(function (el){
     el.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation()
     })
 })

Comment: Problems appear, if you have checkboxes inside.

Comment: if you are using bootstrap 5 then it's very easy https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior

Answer (score 54):

The absolute best answer is to put a form tag after the class dropdown-menu

so your code is

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <form>
    <li>
      <div class="menu-item">bla bla bla</div>
    </li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Comment: this broke my dropdown

Comment: functionally worked splendidly for me, but broke the styling

Comment: this was the fastest solution for me

Comment: This isn't a best answer :) an `<li>` element should not be inside a `<form> ` element.

Comment: See Илья Баранов's answer, where bootstrap stops a click for dropdown with a form. It can be at any level, so the form could go inside the li. Still, this probably breaks quite a few layouts.

Comment: This is not a semanticlly correct solution - the only valid child of a UL is an LI - if anything the form tags should be inside the li tags - but that may not allwo the desired action - either way a ul > form > li  is not correct markup

Comment: Really great! Who could realised that form tag will prevent closing )))) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thnaks for this fast solution

Comment: Again menu closed while clicking top or down on padding of ul :D. So I removed padding of ul and added same padding on form tag. Isn't the best answer but wow it is not using any script.

Comment: This is not a correct solution.Why a form?can you explain?

Comment: If something works, how can it NOT be a correct solution? Why it works is because bootstrap js and jquery both manipulate DOM and neither really care about semantics.

Comment: I've replace ul and li tags with div  and used form, it's still working fine and now it's valid html too.

As for why it works for form because bootstrap support showing a form inside a dropdown (for example login form), in that case it doesn't make sense to hide the popup when clicking on an input field like your username

Comment: Put your entire `<ul>` inside `<form class="dropdown dropdown-item">`

Comment: This simply works, other answers are simply too much work and didn't work.

Comment: Or just replace `<ul>` and `<li>` with `<div>`.

Answer (score 53):

In the new Bootstrap 5 the solution is trivially simple.

Quote from the documentation page:

> By default, the dropdown menu is closed when
> clicking inside or outside the dropdown menu. You can use the
> autoClose option to change this behavior of the dropdown.

In addition to the default behavior, we have 3 options available here:

- Clickable outside: `data-bs-auto-close="outside"`
- Clickable inside: `data-bs-auto-close="inside"`
- Manual close: `data-bs-auto-close="false"`

E.g.:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-auto-close="inside" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickableInside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Clickable inside
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickableInside">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

More info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#auto-close-behavior

Comment: Best answer for anyone using Bootstrap v5!!

Comment: Fantastic!  I knew bootstrap had to have something for this.  Seemed like a trivial thing for them to include since this kind of behavior is asked for so much in previous versions of Bootstrap

Comment: Will it support in BS4 ?

Comment: @ PRANAV unfortunately it will not

Answer (score 49):

[Bootstrap provides the following function:](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#events)

```
                 | This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method 
hide.bs.dropdown | has been called. The toggling anchor element is available as the 
                 | relatedTarget property of the event.
```

Therefore, implementing this function should be able to disable the dropdown from closing.

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.clickEvent.target);
    if(target.hasClass("keepopen") || target.parents(".keepopen").length){
        return false; // returning false should stop the dropdown from hiding.
    }else{
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't want it to close if clicked inside only, not always.

Comment: In that case, use the `event` parameter to determine if the target was one of your carousel buttons. 

    function(e){  
        if(e.target.hasClass('carousel-control'){  
            return false;  
        }  
    }

Comment: @NickG. Not a bad idea, but there are other elements with delegated events : ol > li items (carousel indicators), ... Testing against them all looks a bit `weird solution`. Doesn't it?

Comment: See my new revision. You should be able to add a class "hasopen" to your elements, and they and their parents will cancel the dropdown from closing

Comment: @Vartan, Your solution is `awesome` if we assume that the dropdown menu doesn't change. The carousel controls are just an example. I am dynamically generating the content (It can be anything and not only a carousel, ...) so adding a `keepopen` class is not really possible.

Comment: @Vartan, Also the event `target` property is the `li.dropdown`, the `relatedTarget` is the `a.dropdown-toggle`. So you can't referer to the clicked element within the `hide` event handler.

Comment: @NickG I found one solution. Check it below :)

Comment: hasClass takes a classname, not a CSS selector. `target.hasClass(".keepopen")` should be `target.hasClass("keepopen")`. Otherwise the code won’t work.

Comment: I have scanned the internet and this is the most intelligent solution by far, for this reason... msot other methods call for an approach that uses stopping the default event or stopping propagation. these approaches are very bad as they will break any other triggered events inside the drop down (i.e. my jquery mobile form elements) using this approach allows you to specifically identify when the menu itself is closing and allow you to take action on that event alone. this answer needs so many stars....

Comment: @webfish How much did it take you to scan the internet? (rofl)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much better than a click handler on the whole body, especially if you're using Angular/React/etc.

Comment: Maybe this used to work.. but with bootstrap 4, e.target is always the dropdown itself.  Not the clicked target.  Even if you click outside the dropdowns, e.target is still the dropdown.  So you cannot perform this kind of check.  Anyone see a way around this?

Comment: Can some one supply the HTML that would match the JS solution above, I'm struggling to get this to work with BS3?

Comment: @FredArters I modified Vartan's answer to make it work with BS4. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside/55435771#55435771

Comment: It worked for me when I had the bootstrap-select button click which was inside the dropdown menu of bootstrap 4 navbar.

Comment: This solution worked for me. And also preferable because it feels like the "bootstrap way" of handling things.

Answer (score 47):

I just add onclick event like below to not close dropdown-menu.

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" aria-labelledby="triggerId">
```

Comment: This seems to be a correct answer for Bootstrap@5.0.0-Beta3

Comment: This worked for me like a charm, thanks

Comment: this should be on top this is by far the simplest and less code answer

Comment: Just to point out that, while the other good answers are similar, this approach is by far the easiest to implement and works as expected.

Comment: If you have a form inside the dropdown-menu it will not allow you to select any radio ro checkboxes.

Answer (score 45):

This might help:

```
$("dropdownmenuname").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: This is definitely the simplest/best answer if you want a user to interact with a UI element present on the dropdown (e.g. radio buttons) and don't want the menu to close when they toggle options.

Answer (score 33):

I also found a solution.

Assuming that the `Twitter Bootstrap Components` related events handlers are delegated to the `document` object, I loop the attached handlers and check if the current clicked element (or one of its parents) is concerned by a delegated event.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    var events = $._data(document, 'events') || {};
    events = events.click || [];
    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        if(events[i].selector) {

            //Check if the clicked element matches the event selector
            if($(event.target).is(events[i].selector)) {
                events[i].handler.call(event.target, event);
            }

            // Check if any of the clicked element parents matches the 
            // delegated event selector (Emulating propagation)
            $(event.target).parents(events[i].selector).each(function(){
                events[i].handler.call(this, event);
            });
        }
    }
    event.stopPropagation(); //Always stop propagation
});
```

Hope it helps any one looking for a similar solution.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Wow!!! worked perfectly! Was in trouble for a week , I am using mCustomeScrollbar and after clicking on scrollbar in drop down it was closing it, your script worked and now its working fine! Thanks a million.

Comment: works great! how does one extend this, so that a user can still press "ESC" (or even click outside) on keyboard to close the DD?

Comment: @MaggewDotCom The ESC key press should still work. The same for clicking outside ...

Comment: The only downside of this solution is that it doesn't allow nested dropdowns (say you have a dropright inside a dropdown). Is there a workaround for this case?

Answer (score 24):

```
$('body').on("click", ".dropdown-menu", function (e) {
    $(this).parent().is(".open") && e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This may work for any conditions.

Comment: this should be the correct answer as it uses fewer lines of code  rather than the selected answer

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Nah! As it doesn't fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 18):

I tried this simple thing and it worked like a charm.

I changed the **dropdown-menu** element from `<div>` to `<form>` and it worked well.

```
<div class="nav-item dropdown" >
  <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Click to open dropdown
 </a>
 <form class="dropdown-menu   ">
  <ul class="list-group text-black">
     <li class="list-group-item"  >
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item"   >
     </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="nav-item dropdown" >
  <a href="javascript:;" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Click to open dropdown
 </a>
 <form class="dropdown-menu   ">
  <ul class="list-group text-black">
     <li class="list-group-item"  >
      List Item 1
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item"   >
         LI 2<input class="form-control" />
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item"   >
        List Item 3
     </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: For me this only worked with the surrounding `<div class="dropdown"></div>`, but then very well.

Answer (score 13):

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown.keep-inside-clicks-open', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown keep-inside-clicks-open">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
     Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Demo**:

Generic:
https://jsfiddle.net/kerryjohnson/omefq68b/1/

Your demo with this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kerryjohnson/80oLdtbf/101/

Answer (score 12):

I modified @Vartan's answer to make it work with Bootstrap 4.3. His solution doesn't work anymore with the latest version as `target` property always returns dropdown's root `div` no matter where the click was placed.

Here is the code:

```js
$('.dropdown-keep-open').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
  if (!e.clickEvent) {
    // There is no `clickEvent` property in the `e` object when the `button` (or any other trigger) is clicked. 
    // What we usually want to happen in such situations is to hide the dropdown so we let it hide. 
    return true;
  }

  var target = $(e.clickEvent.target);

  return !(target.hasClass('dropdown-keep-open') || target.parents('.dropdown-keep-open').length);
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown dropdown-keep-open">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oneline: `$('.dropdown-keep-open').on('hide.bs.dropdown', ev => !(ev.clickEvent && $(ev.target).has(ev.clickEvent.target).length))`

Comment: @MatveevDmitriy I'm sorry but no one, simply no one can read this one liner. Writing code this way is imho a bad practice.

Comment: The last line can be simplified using `return !target.closest('.dropdown-keep-open').length)`. That said, this is a great solution! Found this needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 10):

```
$('body').on("click", ".dropdown-menu", function (e) {
    $(this).parent().is(".show") && e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. The question is already answered. Also, I have a different requirement as described in the question than the common requirement.

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 5

If anyone comes to this via Google wanting a Bootstrap 5 version like I was, it's built in by adding `data-bs-auto-close="outside"`. Note the option is `autoClose` but when passing as a data attribute the camelcasing is removed & separated by a dash.

I have a collapse widget in a dropdown & adding `data-bs-auto-close="outside"` to the parent `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` trigger keeps the dropdown open while the collapse is toggled.

See official Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#options
And this codepen for example code (not my pen): https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/BaReWGe

Answer (score 7):

Like for instance Bootstrap 4 Alpha has this Menu Event. Why not use?

```
// PREVENT INSIDE MEGA DROPDOWN
$('.dropdown-menu').on("click.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();                
});
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` blocks links, you can skip it

Comment: @czachor  you're Right!        
   **e.preventDefault();**  Prevent a link from following the URL.

Answer (score 7):

Bootstrap has solved this problem themselves in their support for `<form>` tags in dropdowns. Their solution is quite graspable and you can read it here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/dropdown.js

It boils down to preventing propagation at the document element and doing so only for events of type `'click.bs.dropdown.data-api'` that match the selector `'.dropdown .your-custom-class-for-keep-open-on-click-elements'`.

Or in code

```
$(document).on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown .keep-open-on-click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you for the link to the source.  For others wondering why the `form` approach from the examples isn't working for you - I was using class `dropleft`, but it also needs `dropdown` in order for the form-selector to match.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `form` tag. Example:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <form>
        Anything inside this wont close the dropdown!
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Click me!"/>
    </form>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clik this and the dropdown will be closed</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">This too</a>
</div>
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#forms

Answer (score 6):

I've got a similar problem recently and tried different ways to solve it with removing the data attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` and listening `click` with `event.stopPropagation()` calling.

The second way looks more preferable. Also Bootstrap developers use this way.
In the source file I found initialization of the dropdown elements:

```
// APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
$(document)
.on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
.on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
.on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
.on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
.on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown-menu', Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
}(jQuery);
```

So, this line:

```
.on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
```

suggests you can put a `form` element inside the container with class `.dropdown` to avoid closing the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply execute `event.stopPropagation` on click event of the links themselves.
Something like this.

```
    $(".dropdown-menu a").click((event) => {
         event.stopPropagation()
         let url = event.target.href
         //Do something with the url or any other logic you wish
    })
```

Edit: If someone saw this answer and is using react, it will not work.
React handle the javascript events differently and by the time your react event handler is being called, the event has already been fired and propagated. To overcome that you should attach the event manually like that

```
handleMenuClick(event) {
   event.stopPropagation()
   let menu_item = event.target
   //implement your logic here.
}
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")[0].addEventListener(
        "click", this.handleMenuClick.bind(this), false)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can stop click on the dropdown from propagating and then manually reimplement the carousel controls using [carousel javascript methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$('a.left').click(function () {
    $('#carousel').carousel('prev');
});

$('a.right').click(function () {
    $('#carousel').carousel('next');
});

$('ol.carousel-indicators li').click(function (event) {
    var index = $(this).data("slide-to");
    $('#carousel').carousel(index);
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo93ba38/).

Comment: Your example works fine but the problem is that the dropdown can hold any content and not only images carousel ...

Answer (score 4):

> - **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4y8tLgcp/

```
$('ul.nav.navbar-nav').on('click.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    var $a  = $(e.target), is_a = $a.is('.is_a');
    if($a.hasClass('dropdown-toggle')){   
        $('ul.dropdown-menu', this).toggle(!is_a);
        $a.toggleClass('is_a', !is_a);
    }
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('ul.dropdown-menu',this).hide();
    $('.is_a', this).removeClass('is_a');
});
```

i have updated it once again to be the smartest and functional as possible. it now close when you hover outside the nav, remaining open while you are inside it. simply perfect.

Comment: Your solution is smart due to its shortness, however, after added the class `show`, the dropdown doesn't close on click outside, and we need to click on the dropdown-toggle before ... +1 anyway

Comment: i have updated it, look at the demo. it is the best cause don't check against the body click event everytime. affect only element inside each single nav element not outside of it.

Comment: My solution also don't rely on `body` click event ^^

Comment: yes, it relay in part on body click event, it try to check what element has been clicked trought the body delegation. `$('body').on('click', function (e) {`

Comment: Nah! That's not my answer. My answer is the last posted one.

Answer (score 3):

I know there already is a previous answer suggesting to use a form but the markup provided is not correct/ideal. Here's the easiest solution, no javascript needed at all and it doesn't break your dropdown. Works with Bootstrap 4.

`<form class="dropdown-item">
       <!-- Your elements go here -->
</form>`

Comment: @RosdiKasim I have it working fine on a website with Bootstrap 4.0.0. Haven't tested with 4.1

Comment: Actually it should be like : <form class="dropdown dropdown-item">

Answer (score 2):

With Angular2 Bootstrap, you can use nonInput for most scenarios:

```
<div dropdown autoClose="nonInput">
```

> nonInput - (default) automatically closes the dropdown when any of its elements is clicked — as long as the clicked element is not an input or a textarea.

https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6][Rails]
For rails developer, `e.stopPropagation()` will lead to undesirable behavior for `link_to` with `data-method` not equal to `get` since it will by default return all your request as `get`.

To remedy this problem, I suggest this solution, which is universal

```
$('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').on('click.bs.dropdown', function() {
  return $('.dropdown').one('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

```js
$('.dropdown .dropdown-menu').on('click.bs.dropdown', function() {
  return $('.dropdown').one('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Menu item 1
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel"></li>
            <li class="active" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <img alt="" class="img-rounded" src="img1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item active">
              <img alt="" class="img-rounded" src="img2.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This helped me,

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
     if ($(this).parent().is(".open")) {
         var target = $(e.target);
         if (target.hasClass("keepopen") || target.parents(".keepopen").length){
                    return false; 
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }            
});
```

Your drop down menu element needs to be like this, (take a note of the classes `dropdown-menu` and `keepopen`.

```
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu topmenu-menu eserv_top_notifications keepopen">
```

The above code prevents biding on the whole `<body>`, instead to the specfic element with the class `dropdown-menu`.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Updated As Per Bootstrap 4     $('.dropdown-menu[data-handledropdownclose="true"]').on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(this).parent().is(".show")) {
            var target = $(e.target);

            return (target.hasClass("CloseDropDown") || target.parents(".CloseDropDown").length);
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was specifically for jQuery, but for anyone using AngularJS that has this problem you can create a directive that handles this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('dropdownPreventClose', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); //prevent the default behavior of closing the dropdown-menu
          });
        }
    };
});
```

Then just add the attribute `dropdown-prevent-close` to your element that is triggering the menu to close, and it should prevent it.  For me, it was a `select` element that automatically closed the menu:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <select dropdown-prevent-close name="myInput" id="myInput" ng-model="myModel">
    <option value="">Select Me</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ```<div class="dropdown-menu" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">``` works for me in 1.2.x

Answer (score 1):

The simplest working solution for me is:

- adding `keep-open` class to elements that should not cause dropdown closing
- and this piece of code do the rest:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    var dropdown = target.closest('.dropdown');
    return !dropdown.hasClass('open') || !target.hasClass('keep-open');
});
```

Comment: can you please help me to fix this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552712/angular-4-mega-menu-is-not-closed-after-clicked-on-a-menu-inside-it @Gee-Bee

Answer (score 1):

I've found none of the solutions worked as I would like using default bootstrap nav. 
Here is my solution to this problem:

```
       $(document).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget.activeElement).hasClass('dropdown-toggle')) {
          $(e.relatedTarget).parent().removeClass('open');
          return true;
        }
        return false;
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing some javascript or jquery code(reinventing the wheel). The above scenario can be managed by bootstrap auto-close option.
You can provide either of the values to **auto-close**:

1. always - (Default) automatically closes the dropdown when any of its elements is clicked.
2. outsideClick - closes the dropdown automatically only when the user clicks any element outside the dropdown.
3. disabled - disables the auto close

Take a look at the following plunkr :

http://plnkr.co/edit/gnU8M2fqlE0GscUQtCWa?p=preview

Set

```
uib-dropdown auto-close="disabled"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It should be explicitly noted that this is only good for people using `ui-bootstrap`, which is probably not the case for very many people viewing this question.

Comment: You well described but I think you should write solution as `uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick"`. Menu close on click inside is just a little disconfort but menu not close on click outside is quite upsetting.

Answer (score 1):

In `.dropdown` content put the `.keep-open` class on any label like so:

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    var dropdown = target.closest('.dropdown');
    if (target.hasClass('keep-open')) {
        $(dropdown).addClass('keep-open');
    } else {
        $(dropdown).removeClass('keep-open');
    }
});

$(document).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if ($(target).is('.keep-open')) {
        return false
    }
});
```

The previous cases avoided the events related to the container objects, now  the container inherits the class keep-open and check before being closed.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with this:

```js
$(element).on({
    'mouseenter': function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).data('mouseover', true);
    },
    'mouseleave': function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).data('mouseover', false);
    },
    'hide.bs.dropdown': function (event) {
        return !$(event.currentTarget).data('mouseover');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the below code to solve this.

```js
$(document).on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.keep_it_open', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown keep_it_open">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4

```
$('.dropdown-menu[data-handledropdownclose="true"]').on("click.bs.dropdown", function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("show")) {
        var target = $(e.target);

        if (!(target.hasClass("CloseDropDown") || target.parents(".CloseDropDown").length)) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
});

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn-no-border dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <img src="~/Content/CSS/CssImages/Icons/usr_icon.png" alt="" title="language" class="float-right" />
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu profile-menu-logout" data-handledropdownclose="true">
        <div class="prof-name">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Hello World
        </div>

        <hr />

        <div>
            <a href="/Test/TestAction" class="CloseDropDown">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                <span>Test Action</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav-menu-prof padding-0">
                    <li class="menu-has-children">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="cyan-text-color">
                                Test 2
                            </span>
                        </a>

                        <ul id="ulList" class="padding-0 pad-left-25">
                            <li>
                                <a href="/Test/Test2" class="action currentmenu"> Test 1 </a>
                                <a href="/Test/Test2" class="action CloseDropDown"> Test 2 </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="/Account/Logout" class="cyan-text-color CloseDropDown">
                <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
                <span>Logout</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.mega-dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        return !($target.hasClass("keep-open") || $target.parents(".keep-open").size() > 0);
    });

    $('.mega-dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('keep-open')
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).parent('li').removeClass('keep-open')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For closing the dropdown only if a click event was triggered outside the bootstrap dropdown, this is what worked for me:

JS file:

```
    $('.createNewElement').on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.tags-btn-group.keep-open-dropdown', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (target.hasClass("dropdown-menu") || target.parents(".dropdown-menu").length) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
```

HTML file:

```
<!-- button: -->
<div class="createNewElement">
                <div class="btn-group tags-btn-group keep-open-dropdown">

                    <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">OPEN DROPDOWN</div>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        WHAT EVER YOU WANT HERE...
                    </ul>

                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have some problems if you use return false or stopPropagation() method because your events will be interrupted.
Try this code, it's works fine:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown').on("click", function (e) {
            $('.keep-open').removeClass("show");
    });
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on("click", function () {
            $('.keep-open').addClass("show");
    });

    $( ".closeDropdown" ).click(function() {
        $('.dropdown').closeDropdown();
    });
});
jQuery.fn.extend({
    closeDropdown: function() {
        this.addClass('show')
            .removeClass("keep-open")
            .click()
            .addClass("keep-open");
    }
  });
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown keep-open" id="search-menu" >
    <button  class="btn dropdown-toggle btn  btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-filter fa-fw"></i> 
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <button class="dropdown-item" id="opt1" type="button">Option 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" id="opt2" type="button">Option 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary closeDropdown">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to close the dropdrown:

```
`$('#search-menu').closeDropdown();`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).click(function (event) {
    $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.closest('#DivdropFilterListItemsCustomer').length == 1) {
        $('#DivdropFilterListItemsCustomer').addClass('dropdown-menu show');        
    } else {
        $('#DivdropFilterListItemsCustomer').removeClass('dropdown-menu 
           show').addClass('dropdown-menu');
    }
});
DivdropFilterListItemsCustomer is id of drop down 
 [Show id and drop down ][1]
```

#A2ZCode

Comment: Please explain your answer and how it answers the question's concerns.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
var closeble = false;
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(event.target).is("a.dropdown-toggle")) {
        closeble = false;
    }

});
$('.dropdown').on({
    "click": function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest('.dropdown-toggle').length) {
            closeble = true;
        } else {
            closeble = false;
        }
    },
    "hide.bs.dropdown": function() {
        return closeble;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of only showing code, try to write a good answer following these points: [answer]. Also this question already had 19 answers, how does your solution differs from others?

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap 4 you can also do this:

```
$('#dd-link').on('hide.bs.dropdown', onListHide)

function onListHide(e)
{
  if(e.clickEvent && $.contains(e.relatedTarget.parentNode, e.clickEvent.target)) {
  e.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

where `#dd-link` is the anchor element or button that has the `data-toggle="drowndown"` property.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add "hold-on-click" to "dropdown-menu" class

Comment: ...What does .hold-on-click do, and what library does it come from?