# ember.js + bootstrap popover - Get controller variable in popover content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, controller, popover

How can I pass a variable defined in a controller to a popover defined in the corresponding template?
So, I have a pretty standard bootstrap popover defined in my project like so:

**li tag that triggers the popover**

```
<li data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-popover-content="#earnings">
  <div><img {{bind-attr src="this.photo"}}></div>
</li>
```

**#earnings div for data-popover-content**

```
<div id="earnings" class="hidden">
   {{#each controller_variable}}
     //code
   {{else}}
     //code
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

**controller_variable**

```
controller_variable: function(){
  var information; //pseudo-code
  return information;
}.property()
```

**javascript to handle popover**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
      html : true,
      content: function() {
        var content = $(this).attr("data-popover-content");
        return $(content).html();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The `controller_variable` contains 5 objects in an array, but the `{{else}}` block is being displayed meaning there is nothing in `controller_variable`.

I feel like it has something to do with the fact that the popover content is hidden, but is there a standard way of what I'm trying to do? Let me know if something's not clear.

Comment: You shouldn't place the popover code outside view or component. I would recommended you to use preprepared bootstrap popover compontent.  It is not going to work, because you probably lost some bindings.

Comment: i wanted to do the same thing and ended up using a dropdown menu instead of a popover.  to do this, you need to handle the opening/closing yourself.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/