# Dropdown closes after every click

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Dropdown closes after every mouse click. The dropdown should close only after hitting the "Close (X)" button. How can I do that? 
Plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7mcBoyfbrT3FNl2vJLjh?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this in native bootstrap then this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside) is right.

But, I would recommend you using [angular ui bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). as, you are using angular.js(in plunker) and **angular ui bootstrap** provides all bootstrap components as directives. and you won't have to write angular wrapper around native bootstrap components.

Luckily, dropdown in angular ui bootstrap provides option for `auto-close`  which you can set to `outsideClick` so it won't close when you click inside inside dropdown.

**[Angular UI Bootstrap Dropdown Docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)**

See the working example below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.closeDropDown = function() {
    $scope.isopen = false;
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="isopen" auto-close="outsideClick">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        Options <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
          <ul>
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox">Open
            </label>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <label class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox">Close
            </label>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" ng-click="closeDropDown()">Close (X)</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This module is working exactly the way I wanted. But, with I plugged it in my HTML page, it get a error saying "Attribute auto close is not allowed". What can I do to debug the errors?

Comment: are you using _angular ui bootstrap_ in your code ?

Comment: Yes I am, i include <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script> in my HTML  and  angular.module('mySupport', ['ui.bootstrap']); in my JS.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle or plunker so i can take a look at the code ? without seeing code i can't say what's going wrong in it.

Comment: I have commented out all the other HTML code so that it is easier for you to check on the code.

Comment: @Anu see this http://plnkr.co/edit/1d3rZl7D3aiRNQZpUF1E?p=preview. I have added CDN links for angular ui bootstrap files. commented some of the unnecessary code. and also did changes in `app.js`. there is no need of using _angular ui bootstrap_ and _native bootstrap_ both choose one of them.

Comment: Do you have any idea on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367621/unable-to-display-right-tick-mark-in-checkbox-in-tablets-and-ipad