# Unable to display right tick mark in checkbox in tablets and iPad

Tags: ipad, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following code, it displays check mark ticked on desktop. But doesn't work on iPad and tablets. Functionality is working but right mark is not shown.

```html
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 borderAtRight" 
     
  <!--  Dropdown and Menu -->
  <div class="btn-group topFilterCtrl filterDropdn" dropdown 
    dropdown-append-to-body
    id="ddlStatus">
      <div id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary panelTextFont14 noBorder"   
        dropdown-toggle>
        Status<span class="caret caretSpan"></span>
      </div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownLabel" role="menu" 
        aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body" 
        ng-show="!vm.showthis">
          <div class="customScroll">
            <li role="menuitem" class="changeColorOnHover"
              ng-repeat="optionThis in vm.List track by $index" 
              ng-show="list.value != null">
              <a href="#">
              <div class="checkbox" id="{}index}"
                ng-show="this.value != null"
                ng-click="vm.applyFilterForResultCount()"
                ng-change="vm.getCount(this)"
                ng-model="this.flag">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" 
                    ng-click="vm.clickStatusCheckBox(this);$event.stopPropagation();" 
                    ng-show="this.value != null"/>
                  {{this.value}}
                </label>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <!--Clear div-->
        <li role="menuitem" class="btn btn-default buttonli"
          ng-click="vm.clearAll()">
          <a href="#">
            <p>
              <span class="clearAllBtn">Clear</span>
              <span class="dropDownBtnItem">  – All </span>
            </p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.topFilterCtrl{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 8%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-top: 0%;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border:none;
    width:100%;
}

portrait:

div.borderAtRight .filterDropdn{
    padding-top:14%;
}

.filterDropdn{
    padding-top: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.noBorder{
    text-align: left;
    width:@full-width;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    min-width: 80%;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 36px;
    border-top-color: none;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-top-width: none;
    border-right-color: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: none;
    border-bottom-color: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-bottom-width: none;
    border-left-color: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: none;
}

.dropDownLabel{
    margin:0 0 0 -16px;
}

.customScroll{
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:360px;
}

.customScroll>li>a, 
.customScroll>li>a:hover, 
.customScroll>li>a:active, 
.customScroll>li>a:focus {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 22px;
    clear: both;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration : none;
}

.buttonli {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#E4EAEF;
}

li.buttonli > a > p{
    margin-bottom:0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

I found this: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2017

But not sure how do I implement it, where should I really include this directive in my code as I am very new to AJS?

Comment: Is the checkbox not displaying at all on the iPad, or is it that the checkbox is not ticked by default on the iPad?

Comment: checkbox is visible but its right tick mark is not visible.

Comment: Can you please give a screenshot of what it looks like when it's displaying correctly? It's very difficult to see what's going on with the mix of HTML/CSS/Angular.

Comment: added screenshot for Apple iPad

Comment: Thanks. What does it look like on the desktop version?

Comment: Added desktop screenshot

Comment: What other styling is applying to the checkbox? I'm wondering why the `-webkit-appearance: checkbox;` is needed...

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox may not display correct because the `input` element is nested inside the `label` element (even though it may be allowed, it confuses the purposes of the input and the label).

If the issue is about the checkbox not being checked by default, you might need to check out the `ng-checked="expression"` syntax for Angular.

Comment: Removing the label also did not help!