# bootstrap 3, problems with collapsed menu over slideshow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, nav

I have a site in development which is looking Ok, but I have a problem which only occurs with the collapsed menu, and only on the home page.

On the homepage there is a full width slideshow, if i try and navigate to a dropdown item, eg the gallery, the menu closes. It isn't an issue on any other page, and I am finding it difficult to debug.

http://test.forthwebsolutions.com

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common Twitter Bootstrap behavior using the `data-toggle="dropdown"`.

To avoid this, the most simplest trick is - attach a click event handler on the internal dropdown menu and simply add `event.stopPropagation()`. Like so.

```
$('li.dropdown.inside-dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event){
    // The event won't be propagated up to the document NODE and 
    // therefore delegated events won't be fired
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and obviously for that you need to also add the class that i mentioned above to the internal dropdown menus. For example:

```
<li class="dropdown inside-dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Galleries <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu open">
        <li><a href="/gallery.php">Image Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/video_gallery.php">Video Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Additional Information : *If your curious, there are alternative methods as well if you do not want to use `event.stopPropagation()` which is mentioned [here in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have marked your answer as useful. It didn;t solve my problem however, so I looked through some backups and found the problem did not occur on an earlier version. For some reason, I had a block of js on my slideshow plugin which toggled the navbar-toggle class on clicking .nav a - i have commented this out and it is now working fine