# How avoid that when I click on the menu it disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button and when I click it open a " dropdown-toggle" where the are different checkbox and label. My purpose is select more check box in the same time without reload "dropbox-toggle. Now in my code when I click on the checkbox the "dropbox-toggle" is reload and when I click again I see the checkbox select.This is my html code:

```
    <div class="btn-group open">
         <button id="bookmarked_button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" type="button">

         <span class="visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline">Bookmarked</span>
         <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="ul_menu">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="dsfasd">dsfasd</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="scorrere">scorrere</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="piscol">piscol</li>
<li><a href="#" id="aggiungi_bookmarked"><i class="fa fa-fw fa fa-plus"></i>Aggiungi Bookmarked</a></li></ul></div>
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: See this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside

Comment: Show your js code. What you have tried so far?