# Open bootstrap sub nav menu if that is the parent of the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello fellow stackoverflowers!

I am currently making a mobile site with bootstrap 3. The site only has 2 levels of pages...main menu and then certain pages have sub menus.

If I am on a sub-page and I open the menu I would like that parent to be open so that I can see what page I am on with the parent expanded.

In the DOM I can do this very easily by adding the class 'open' to `<li class="dropdown">`

The problem is that when I tell my cms to work out if this page is a child and then to add that class, it does it fine but bootstrap seems to be automatically removing it? The 'open' class is there when I view source but not when I inspect the element. If I remove the bootstrap js then the class is there when I inspect so it is bootstrap that is removing it.

I have tried manually adding the class with javascript and that doesnt work...I have tried using the `$().dropdown('toggle')` from the bootstrap docs but that doesnt work...I even tried finding the element and then trigerring a jquery .click method and that doesnt work either so im a bit stumped...

Cheers

Matt

Comment: The problem is that Bootstrap creates dropdown backdrop, so when you click on the hamburger menu, it removes `open` class from your dropdown.

Comment: Is there a way to make it stop doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25196101/3258604