# How to prevent dropdown close on menu item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web

how to prevent dropdown menu close on menu item click. I tried to do something but it does not work.

```
<script>
// Do not close dropdown on menu item click
$(document).on('click', '.list-dropdown', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Fixed with line:** onclick="event.stopPropagation();"

Comment: Try giving e.preventDefault(); to avoid default property of that  dropdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap - Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside)

Comment: @HemaNandagopal e.preventDefault(); I tried but it does not work.

Comment: @Chris I saw this post but it does not work me or I writed something wrong.

Comment: add return after e.preventDefaults()

Comment: post your html here!

Answer (score 0):

Use this where you have e.stopPropagation:

```
e.preventDefault();
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop propagation prevents the event from propagating to other methods. But what you are looking to do here, is stop the default behaviour (which is close the menu).

Your code should look like the following:

```
<script>
// Do not close dropdown on menu item click
$(document).on('click', '.list-dropdown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: But it does not work for me. Only this one work: onclick="event.stopPropagation();"

Comment: That then means that the element who is closing the dropdown is not the `.list-dropdown` but some other