# Bootstrap 4 - Drop-down disappearing when i click on the tabs inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i'm using bootstrap 4 & i have successfully added the nav tab to dropdown. when i click on the tabs the dropdown is hiding. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside), Though, i couldn't achive the result. How to prevent dropdown from hiding when i click on the tab in the dropdown. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome-5.0.9/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left dropdown-menu-tip-ne recent-projects" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="width:350px">
            <nav>
              <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">profile....</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">home.....</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">contact.....</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside).

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(event) {
  var events = $._data(document, 'events') || {};
  events = events.click || [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (events[i].selector) {

      //Check if the clicked element matches the event selector
      if ($(event.target).is(events[i].selector)) {
        events[i].handler.call(event.target, event);
      }

      // Check if any of the clicked element parents matches the 
      // delegated event selector (Emulating propagation)
      $(event.target).parents(events[i].selector).each(function() {
        events[i].handler.call(this, event);
      });
    }
  }
  event.stopPropagation(); //Always stop propagation
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fontawesome-5.0.9/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left dropdown-menu-tip-ne recent-projects" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="width:350px">
            <nav>
              <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">profile....</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">home.....</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">contact.....</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```