# Bootstrap 4 Tabs inside drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I am using boostrap 4 drop down menu with tabs inside. Here is the codepin
I found this link useful to stop click event propagation so that the drop down menu does not close on click inside it[Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside/25253002#25253002)

**But** clicking on tabs does not work.
  code pin:[boostrap 4 tabs inside drop down menu](https://codepen.io/elhaw/pen/JZjJpJ?editors=1010)

```
is there any solution or another approach so that tabs work inside drop down menu
```

---

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     Navbar
</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
</button>
<div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                 Home
                <span class="sr-only">
                     (current)
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                 Features
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                 Pricing
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <div class="container">
                    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="tab-A" class="nav-link active" role="tab" href="#pane-A" data-toggle="tab">
                                 &ndash;A&ndash;
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="tab-B" class="nav-link" role="tab" href="#pane-B" data-toggle="tab">
                                 &ndash;B&ndash;
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="tab-C" class="nav-link" role="tab" href="#pane-C" data-toggle="tab">
                                 &ndash;C&ndash;
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="content" class="tab-content" role="tablist">
                        <div id="pane-A" class="card tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-A">
                            <div id="heading-A" class="card-header" role="tab">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    <a href="#collapse-A" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-A">
                                         Collapsible Group Item A
                                    </a>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse-A" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    [Tab content A]
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pane-B" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-B">
                            <div id="heading-B" class="card-header" role="tab">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    <a class="collapsed" href="#collapse-B" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-B">
                                         Collapsible Group Item B
                                    </a>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse-B" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    [Tab content B]
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="pane-C" class="card tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-C">
                            <div id="heading-C" class="card-header" role="tab">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    <a class="collapsed" href="#collapse-C" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#content" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-C">
                                         Collapsible Group Item C
                                    </a>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse-C" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-C">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    [Tab content C]
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**JS**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on("click.bs.dropdown", function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); });
```

---

Is there possible solution ?

Comment: @ZimSystem added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to wrap it inside a `form` since the form will prevent the Dropdown from closing on click...

```
<nav>
    ...
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
             <form>
                 <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Dropdown link
                 </a>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu">
                     ....
                 </div>
            </form>
    </li>
    ...
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/GzekeuWnSg

The other method is using jQuery to like this:

```
$('.dropdown-menu .nav-tabs .nav-link').on("click.bs.dropdown", function (e) { 
    $(this).tab('show'); 
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/iEDxVGTzAZ

Comment: The best answer is a hack, Thanks :) @ZimSystem

Comment: That's it? I never thought its as simple as this. Nice hack. How on earth you found this?

Comment: @SurjithSM Probably by default bootstrap prevent form interaction to close the dropdown, as you can see in documentation the dropdown can contain form
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/
Bootstrap not specificly mention that thou...