# How to stop dropdown from closing the entire parent panel [Angular]

Tags: html, angular, dom

I've a dropdown component which is inside a custom parent component `timeselector`. I've tried taking help from:

1. [How to avoid dropdown menu to close menu items on clicking inside](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-avoid-dropdown-menu-to-close-menu-items-on-clicking-inside/)
2. [Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside)

and rest of the solutions are using some library or the other. But here I'm creating this component from scratch without `bootstrap`, `primeng` or `material` (* because my team lead doesn't want to use them for some reasons, I didn't argue). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

The widget pops up on click event. As you can see I've a dropdown with four options, but the moment I click on any option, the entire widget simply collapses. However that option gets selected anyway. But the widget collapses back. See the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code. Please correct me where I am wrong.

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<div class="time-selector">
  <p-overlayPanel class="my-overlay" #op>
    <div class="inner-panel">
      <h3>Time selection</h3>
      <br>
      <select [(ngModel)]="mode" name="source" placeholder={{selectedSource}}>
        <option *ngFor="let source of sources" [value]="source">
          <h4>{{source}}</h4>
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </p-overlayPanel>
</div>

<input class="input-field" (click)="op.toggle($event)">
```

**timeselector.component.css**

```
.inner-panel {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.my-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 15px #888888;
  margin-top: 35px;
  right: 0.5%;
}

select {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {

  public selectedSource = 'Calendar year';

  public sources  = ['Calendar year', 'Year-to-date', 'Rolling 12 months', 'Current quarter'];

   @HostListener('document:click') 
    ClickedAway() {
        console.log("inside hostlistener");
    }
}
```

I also read [ElementRef in Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef). I'm using `HostListener` but I'm nor sure how to use it to serve my purpose. Please help me.

Comment: I think a stackblitz will be helpful here

Comment: @NicholasK. Ok I'll quickly create one.

Comment: @NicholasK, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwwy99  .There it is working fine. :-( I think some other component are causing this problem in my project.

Comment: Well, I guess that narrows down your problem then? Since it can't be reproduced don't think we can be of much help.

Comment: As your screenshot seems not to be using a normal (styled) dropdown select I'd guess that the click (select) event is propagated to a point outside of your time selector element.

Comment: Ok guys. Is there any way I can override those properties. As its a huge project and i don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: Overriding is probably not a good idea. Try adjusting the example to reproduce the error, than someone may be able to help.

Comment: @NicholasK. Stackblitz is not possible to create because a lot of things are coming from our organization's own libraries and frameworks. But I tried using `HostListeneter`. Can you see how can we use it correctly here.