# Stop auto-close dropdown menu after click on a link

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have dropdown menu from bootstrap 4.In adaptive small screen, I have hamburger, there has title dropdown its opens another one dropdown.So, when I open title dropdown to see what inside, dropdown automatically close full dropdown. Here`s code

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-translate">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="./" rel="tooltip" title="Казахстанский инженерно-технологический университет" data-placement="bottom">
        <img src="assets/img/logo_new.png" width="180">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background-color: white;" id="navigation">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="testing">
        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle myclass" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="dropdownMenuButton" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?=$m_admission[$_SESSION['lang']]?></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?page=undergraduate"> <?=$b_undergraduate[$_SESSION['lang']]?> </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="?page=graduate"> <?=$b_graduate[$_SESSION['lang']]?> </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kazetu.edu.kz/sites/dl/" target="_blank"> <?=$b_distance_learning[$_SESSION['lang']]?> </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://college.kazetu.edu.kz/"> <?=$b_college[$_SESSION['lang']]?> </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://zerde.kazetu.kz/?lang=ru" target="_blank"> <?=$zerde_kazetu_reg[$_SESSION['lang']]?> </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid dropdown menu close on click inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside)

Comment: I checked the whole internet but dont find the answer

Comment: thewholeinternet.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I dont fount answer for my question, so, i just write it without bootstrap on clear html and css xD

Comment: Its not an answer, so you should delete it and add it as a comment