# React dropdown, multiselect & search without intermediate closing (on state change)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project with React and Bootstrap. Now I have a 'regular' dropdown where I can select 1 option and it closes.

What I want is:

1. to be able to select multiple options, but not close the dropdown when clicking an option. Rather select multiple options and then close the dropdown by clicking e.g. outside of it.
2. To be able to type in a search bar in the top of the dropdown, without the dropdown closing after each typed letter. The typed text should filter the options in the dropdown as you type.

The searchtext (of the searchbar) and the selected options are all in the state of the component, so I can't manage to keep the dropdown open, as the state changes. Taking `value = {filterText}` away from the searchbar stops closing the dropdown when typing, but the text isn't visible.

So the code now only contains the attempt to make the search bar work. The multiselect isn't implemented here yet, but I'm guessing the issue/solution is similar there. I have implemented another dropdown with multiselect with an ugly workaround, so I'd like to do it better this time.

The code of the dropdown component:

```
import React     from "react"
import { hot }   from 'react-hot-loader/root'
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import { useTranslation, withTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';


class AreaFiltering extends React.Component {


  // ---> Lifecycle functions <---

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.selectStoreFilter       = this.selectStoreFilter.bind(this);
    this.selectTerritoryFilter   = this.selectTerritoryFilter.bind(this);
    this.selectCountryFilter     = this.selectCountryFilter.bind(this);
    this.selectAreaFilter        = this.selectAreaFilter.bind(this);
    this.handleSearchInputChange = this.handleSearchInputChange.bind(this);

    this.storeForId     = this.storeForId.bind(this);
    this.territoryForId = this.territoryForId.bind(this);
    this.countryForId   = this.countryForId.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      selectedStoreFilter:     AreaHelper.defaultSelectedStoreId(this.props.areas),
      selectedTerritoryFilter: AreaHelper.defaultSelectedTerritoryId(this.props.areas),
      selectedCountryFilter:   AreaHelper.defaultSelectedCountryId(this.props.areas),
      filterText:              '',
      filteredCountries:       [],
      filteredTerritories:     [],
      filteredStores:          [],
    };
  }


  // ---> UI interaction functions <---

  selectStoreFilter(storeId)
  {
    // Set selected store.
    this.setState({
      selectedStoreFilter:     storeId,
      selectedTerritoryFilter: null,
      selectedCountryFilter:   null
    });

    // Notify parent about selected store.
    this.props.callbackStoreFilterChanged(storeId);
    this.props.callbackTerritoryFilterChanged(null);
    this.props.callbackCountryFilterChanged(null);
  }


  selectTerritoryFilter(territoryId)
  {
    // Set selected territory.
    this.setState({
      selectedStoreFilter:     null,
      selectedTerritoryFilter: territoryId,
      selectedCountryFilter:   null
    });

    // Notify parent about selected territory.
    this.props.callbackStoreFilterChanged(null);
    this.props.callbackTerritoryFilterChanged(territoryId);
    this.props.callbackCountryFilterChanged(null);
  }


  selectCountryFilter(countryId)
  {
    // Set selected country.
    this.setState({
      selectedStoreFilter:     null,
      selectedTerritoryFilter: null,
      selectedCountryFilter:   countryId
    });

    // Notify parent about selected country.
    this.props.callbackStoreFilterChanged(null);
    this.props.callbackTerritoryFilterChanged(null);
    this.props.callbackCountryFilterChanged(countryId);
  }

  selectAreaFilter(areaType, areaId)
  {
    switch (areaType) {
      case 'store':
        this.selectStoreFilter(areaId);
        break;

      case 'territory':
        this.selectTerritoryFilter(areaId);
        break;

      case 'country':
        this.selectCountryFilter(areaId);
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  // Function to filter data based on filter text
  filterData = (data, filterText) => {
    return data.filter(item =>
      item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())
    );
  }

  // Event handler for search input
  handleSearchInputChange = (e) => {
    const filterText = e.target.value;
    const { areas } = this.props;

    // Filter countries, territories, and stores
    const filteredCountries   = this.filterData(areas.countries, filterText);
    const filteredTerritories = this.filterData(areas.territories, filterText);
    const filteredStores      = this.filterData(areas.stores, filterText);

    this.setState({
      filterText:          filterText,
      filteredCountries:   filteredCountries,
      filteredTerritories: filteredTerritories,
      filteredStores:      filteredStores,
    });
  }


  // ---> Helper functions <---

  storeForId(storeId)
  {
    return this.props.areas.stores.find(s => s.id == storeId);
  }

  territoryForId(territoryId)
  {
    return this.props.areas.territories.find(t => t.id == territoryId);
  }

  countryForId(countryId)
  {
    return this.props.areas.countries.find(c => c.id == countryId);
  }


  render () {
    const {
      selectedStoreFilter, selectedTerritoryFilter, selectedCountryFilter, filterText
    } = this.state;
    const { t } = this.props;
    const _this = this;

    const filteredCountries = filterText
      ? this.filterData(_this.props.areas.countries, filterText)
      : _this.props.areas.countries;

    const filteredTerritories = filterText
      ? this.filterData(_this.props.areas.territories, filterText)
      : _this.props.areas.territories;


    const filteredStores = filterText
      ? this.filterData(_this.props.areas.stores, filterText)
      : _this.props.areas.stores;


    /**
     * A dropdown to filter by areas.
     */
    function AreaFilterDropdown(props)
    {
      var filterButtonTitle = t('Filtering.Area.select_area_filter');
      if (selectedStoreFilter != null)
      {
        filterButtonTitle = selectedStoreFilter == -1
          ? t('Filtering.Area.selected_filter_all_stores')
          : (_this.storeForId(selectedStoreFilter)?.name ?? '—');
      }
      else if (selectedTerritoryFilter != null)
      {
        filterButtonTitle = selectedTerritoryFilter == -1
          ? t('Filtering.Area.selected_filter_all_territories')
          : (_this.territoryForId(selectedTerritoryFilter)?.name ?? '—');
      }
      else if (selectedCountryFilter != null)
      {
        filterButtonTitle = selectedCountryFilter == -1
          ? t('Filtering.Area.selected_filter_all_countries')
          : (_this.countryForId(selectedCountryFilter)?.name ?? '—');
      }

      return (
        <div className="area-filter mb-2 mb-lg-0 align-self-end">
          <div className="btn-group bg-white">
            <button
              className          = "btn bg-white dropdown-toggle"
              type               = "button"
              id                 = "area-filter-dropdown-button"
              data-bs-toggle     = "dropdown"
              data-bs-auto-close = "outside"
              aria-expanded      = "false"
            >
              <i className="bi bi-geo-alt-fill me-2" />
              { StringHelper.breakMiddle(filterButtonTitle, 23) }
            </button>

            <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="area-filter-dropdown-button">
              <div className="mx-3 mb-2">
                  <input
                    type        = "text"
                    className   = "form-control"
                    id          = "area-filter-search-input"
                    placeholder = "@TODO: Translate!"
                    onChange    = {_this.handleSearchInputChange}
                    value       = {filterText}
                  />
              </div>

              {
                filteredCountries.length > 1
                  ? <AllAreasDropdownItem key="all-countries" areaType="country" />
                  : null
              }

              {filteredCountries.map((country) => (
                <AreaDropdownItem
                  key      = {'country-' + country.id}
                  area     = {country}
                  areaType = "country"
                />
              ))}

              <DropdownDivider key="divider_countries-territories" />

              {
                filteredTerritories.length > 1
                  ? <AllAreasDropdownItem key="all-territories" areaType="territory" />
                  : null
              }

              {filteredTerritories.map((territory) => (
                <AreaDropdownItem
                  key      = {'territory-' + territory.id}
                  area     = {territory}
                  areaType = "territory"
                />
              ))}

              <DropdownDivider key="divider_territories-stores" />

              {
                filteredStores.length > 1
                  ? <AllAreasDropdownItem key="all-stores" areaType="store" />
                  : null
              }

              {filteredStores.map((store) => (
                <AreaDropdownItem
                  key      = {'store-' + store.id}
                  area     = {store}
                  areaType = "store"
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }


    /**
     * A single dropdown-item for area-filtering.
     */
    function AreaDropdownItem(props)
    {
      // var areaFilter = props.areaFilter;

      return (
        <li>
          <button
            className=
              {
                (props.areaType == 'country' && selectedCountryFilter == props.area.id)
                || (props.areaType == 'territory' && selectedTerritoryFilter == props.area.id)
                || (props.areaType == 'store' && selectedStoreFilter == props.area.id)
                ? 'dropdown-item active' : 'dropdown-item'
              }
            type="button"
            onClick={ e => _this.selectAreaFilter(props.areaType, props.area.id) }
          >
            {props.area.name}
          </button>
        </li>
      );
    }


    /**
     * A single dropdown-item representing all
     * territories or stores in area-filtering.
     */
    function AllAreasDropdownItem(props)
    {
      return (
        <li>
          <button
            className="dropdown-item fw-bold"
            type="button"
            onClick={ e => _this.selectAreaFilter(props.areaType, -1) }
          >

            {
              props.areaType == 'country'
                ? t('Filtering.Area.selected_filter_all_countries')
                : null
            }

            {
              props.areaType == 'territory'
                ? t('Filtering.Area.selected_filter_all_territories')
                : null
            }

            {
              props.areaType == 'store'
                ? t('Filtering.Area.selected_filter_all_stores')
                : null
            }

            {
              (props.areaType == 'country' && selectedCountryFilter == -1)
              || (props.areaType == 'territory' && selectedTerritoryFilter == -1)
              || (props.areaType == 'store' && selectedStoreFilter == -1)
                ? <i className="bi bi-check float-end" />
                : ''
            }
          </button>
        </li>
      );
    }


    /**
     * A dropdown divider.
     */
    function DropdownDivider(props)
    {
      return (
        <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
      );
    }


    return (

      <AreaFilterDropdown />

    );
  }
}


export default hot(withTranslation()(AreaFiltering));
```

EDIT: As I wrote in the comment to this question, I have now moved the dropdown (the `<ul> ... </ul>` part) to its own sub-component. Now whenever I type something in the searchbar, the dropdown closes, but won't open anymore either, so that has changed.
When inspecting the HTML source, I see that when it closes, the `<ul>` changes from this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="area-filter-dropdown-button" data-popper-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 36px, 0px);">
```

to this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="area-filter-dropdown-button">
```

I don't know if this changes to problem/solution in any way, but I can't seem to get further. With my understanding of React: typing something in the searchbar changes the state (`filterText`). The state-change triggers a re-render and makes the dropdown close. Is this the problem?

Comment: I have moved the dropdown (`<ul> ... </ul>`) part to a separate component. It seems like the problem has just moved to there now and it still closes when typing something in the search box.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65951736/17033432

Comment: That is about clicking inside the dropdown, and not the issue here. My issue is related to the state-update triggering a re-render and closing the dropdown (I suspect)